# Issue with Mongoose Model.Save method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

When i am invoking 'userInfo' method using post api,it's always giving a message 'userSchema.save' is not a function.

what am i doing wrong here?

```
var userModel = mongoose.model('user_details');

module.exports.userInfo = function (req, res) {

        var userSchema = new userModel();

        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            userSchema.emailID= "smid"
            userSchema.loginPassword ="smpaswd"

            userSchema.contactAddress = [{
                addressType: "Communication",           
            }]

            userSchema.favourites = [{
                hospitalid: 1234,            
            }] 

            resolve();

        }).then(function () {
            userSchema.save(function (error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    logger.error("Error while inserting record : - " + error)
                    return res.json({ "Message": error.message.split(":")[2].trim() });
                }
                else {
                    return res.json({ "Message": "Data got inserted successfully" });
                }
            })
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return res.json({ "Message": err.message });
        })   
};
```

Comment: can you please add "exact" error message?

Comment: Error message  - {"Message":"userSchema.save is not a function"}.It's thrown from catch block of promise

Comment: Can you paste your mongoose model schema definition for `user_details`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way you are creating your model object is incorrect. Look at this example, In this example we are passing schema definition as "yourSchema" so you may need to pass your schema definition in object creation.

```
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);

var small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
small.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
})

// or

Tank.create({ size: 'small' }, function (err, small) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
})
```

Something like this

```
//userSchema should exist there
var userModel = mongoose.model('user_details', userSchema);
```

Comment: Schema object is correct.I am importing schema using mongoose.model('user_details'); which is not shown in the question.I was wondering if anything wrong with promise implementation

Comment: even if there is something wrong with your promise implementation, error would have been different. What i am saying is that -> var userModel = mongoose.model('user_details'); this line has some issues. You need to pass schema in this i guess. something like this -> var userModel = mongoose.model('user_details', yourUserSchema);

Comment: Similar to userSchema.emailID= "smid" ,can i write userSchema.contactAddress.addressType= "Communication" for sub documents?I tried,somwhe it's not working

Comment: Yes you can write. what's the error you are getting?

Comment: It's not throwing any error.but array is not getting created.

Comment: Have you added it in definition of schema? Can you please share that ?

Comment: contactAddress: [{
        addressType: { type: String, required: true, enum: ['Communication', 'Permanent'], default: 'Communication' }}]

Comment: You cant add it like this "userSchema.contactAddress.addressType= "Communication" ", as you defined that contactAddress will be array then it has to be added like array.